# Treemap made with D3.js not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, treemap

I'm sorry if that's a silly question, but I'm really new to js, and I'm a bit lost (I should have start with something easier to do >_<). 
I tried to create a treemap displaying political parties per year based on this example : http://bl.ocks.org/4063582

The problem is that my treemap does not function at all on Chrome, athought it does work well on Safari. Here are the files (index + json) that I created : https://www.dropbox.com/sh/z7bre4ffiyc2k8i/e45sJSbK7a

Thanks for all the help you can provide me with! And also if you know a good tutorial to start, I would appreciate =)

Comment: I had a similar problem and I'm still not sure why that is. But it only occured on my local host. After uploading the files to a remote server, the d3.js displayed flawlessly in all browsers.